# Spark 3.0.0 error creating SparkSession: pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: <exception str() failed>

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I'm trying to build Spark 3.0.0 for my Yarn cluster, with Hadoop 2.7.3 and Hive 1.2.1. I downloaded the source and created a runnable dist with

`./dev/make-distribution.sh --name custom-spark --pip --r --tgz -Psparkr -Phive-1.2  -Phadoop-2.7 -Pyarn`

We're running Spark 2.4.0 in production so I copied the hive-site.xml, spark-env.sh and spark-defaults.conf from there.

When I try to create a SparkSession in a normal Python REPL, I get the following uninformative error. How can I debug this? I can run the spark-shell and get to a scala prompt with Hive access seemingly without error.

```
Python 3.6.3 (default, Apr 10 2018, 16:07:04)
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = '/home/pmccarthy/custom-spark-3'
>>> sys.path.insert(0,os.path.join(os.environ['SPARK_HOME'],'python','lib','py4j-src.zip'))
>>> sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['SPARK_HOME'],'python'))
>>> import pyspark
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>> spark = (SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().config('spark.master','local').getOrCreate())
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pmccarthy/custom-spark-3/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 191, in getOrCreate
    session._jsparkSession.sessionState().conf().setConfString(key, value)
  File "/home/pmccarthy/custom-spark-3/python/lib/py4j-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "/home/pmccarthy/custom-spark-3/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 137, in deco
    raise_from(converted)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: <exception str() failed>
```

Comment: It seems like some of your config is not recognised;
`session._jsparkSession.sessionState().conf().setConfString(key, value)`

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/session.py#L181

Comment: After some testing it seems that `enableHiveSupport()` is causing the crashes - if I build a SparkSession without it then it starts up fine. It's still a mystery though, as it crashes the same way whether or not my hive-site.xml has my config or is blank.

Comment: Having similar problems. To get a better error message, we changed https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.0/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py#L29 to be `raise e`

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. It seems that `-Phive-1.2` but not including `-Phive-thriftserver` prevented some necessary jars from being built. After doing that I still didn't have total support, but was able to connect to my metastore with both `.config('spark.sql.hive.metastore.version','1.2.1')` and `.config('spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars','maven')`. It still seems like the build flag implies it should produce a working install for hive 1.2 though.

Answer (score 4):

I also encountered `pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: <exception str() failed>`. It was caused on my side by using an option removed in Spark 3 (`spark.sql.legacy.allowCreatingManagedTableUsingNonemptyLocation`).

Comment: Did you solve the main issue of not being able to write, caused by this which made you use `allowCreatingManagedTableUsingNonemptyLocation`

Comment: Thanks, moving from spark 2 to spark3 this configuration was causing error, I had removed this and it started working.